# Obstacle Avoidance With Walls in C#

Tags: xna, c#, steering-behaviors, collision-avoidance

I'm trying to do some obstacle avoidance. Yet somehow something is not going quite well.
I've used the book "Programming Game AI by Example" to create a simular function in c# in combination with XNA.

This is what i'm doing right now:

```
public Vector2 ObstacleAvoidance(List<Obstacle> obstacles)
        {
            //the detection box length is proportional to the agent's velocity
            Owner.DetectionBox = Owner.MinDetectionBoxLength +
                                         ((Owner.Speed() / Owner.MaxSpeed) * Owner.MinDetectionBoxLength);
            //tag all obstacles within range of the box for processing
            TagObstaclesWithinViewRange(Owner);

            //this will keep track of the closest intersecting obstacle (CIB)
            BaseGameEntity ClosestIntersectingObstacle = null;

            //this will be used to track the distance to the CIB
            double DistToClosestIP = Double.MaxValue;

            //this will record the transformed local coordinates of the CIB
            Vector2 LocalPosOfClosestObstacle = new Vector2();

            foreach (Obstacle curOb in obstacles)
            {
                //if the obstacle has been tagged within range proceed
                if (curOb.Tag)
                {
                    //calculate this obstacle's position in local space
                    Vector2 LocalPos = HelperMethods.PointToLocalSpace(curOb.Position,
                                                           Owner.Heading,
                                                           Owner.Side,
                                                           Owner.Position);

                    //if the local position has a negative x value then it must lay
                    //behind the agent. (in which case it can be ignored)
                    if (LocalPos.X >= 0)
                    {
                        //if the distance from the x axis to the object's position is less
                        //than its radius + half the width of the detection box then there
                        //is a potential intersection.
                        double ExpandedRadius = curOb.BoundingRadius + Owner.BoundingRadius;
                        if (Math.Abs(LocalPos.Y) < ExpandedRadius)
                        {
                            //now to do a line/circle intersection test. The center of the 
                            //circle is represented by (cX, cY). The intersection points are 
                            //given by the formula x = cX +/-sqrt(r^2-cY^2) for y=0. 
                            //We only need to look at the smallest positive value of x because
                            //that will be the closest point of intersection.
                            double cX = LocalPos.X;
                            double cY = LocalPos.Y;

                            //we only need to calculate the sqrt part of the above equation once
                            double SqrtPart = Math.Sqrt(ExpandedRadius * ExpandedRadius - cY * cY);

                            double ip = cX - SqrtPart;

                            if (ip <= 0.0)
                            {
                                ip = cX + SqrtPart;
                            }

                            //test to see if this is the closest so far. If it is keep a
                            //record of the obstacle and its local coordinates
                            if (ip < DistToClosestIP)
                            {
                                DistToClosestIP = ip;

                                ClosestIntersectingObstacle = curOb;

                                LocalPosOfClosestObstacle = LocalPos;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //if we have found an intersecting obstacle, calculate a steering 
            //force away from it
            Vector2 SteeringForce = Vector2.Zero;

            if (ClosestIntersectingObstacle != null)
            {
                //the closer the agent is to an object, the stronger the 
                //steering force should be
                double multiplier = 1.0 + (Owner.DetectionBox - LocalPosOfClosestObstacle.X) /
                                    Owner.DetectionBox;

                //calculate the lateral force
                SteeringForce.Y = (float) ((ClosestIntersectingObstacle.BoundingRadius -
                                            LocalPosOfClosestObstacle.Y) * multiplier);

                //apply a braking force proportional to the obstacles distance from
                //the vehicle. 
                double BrakingWeight = 0.2;

                SteeringForce.X = (float) ((ClosestIntersectingObstacle.BoundingRadius -
                                            LocalPosOfClosestObstacle.X) *
                                           BrakingWeight);
            }

            //finally, convert the steering vector from local to world space
            return HelperMethods.VectorToWorldSpace(SteeringForce,
                                      Owner.Heading,
                                      Owner.Side);
        }
```

When i'm seeing the wall i still go through it instead of changing directions.
This has something to do with this specific line of code:

```
double ExpandedRadius = curOb.BoundingRadius + Owner.BoundingRadius;
if (Math.Abs(LocalPos.Y) < ExpandedRadius)
```

When i'm seeing the wall i should go into this if yet i'm not, and therefore going through the wall.

curOb = the wall and his boudingradius is 12.5.
Owner = the player and his bounding radius is also 12.5.
The LocalPos.Y value is something like 120 which is correct as the y position of the wall is at that exact location. How can i try to fix this so my player won't crash into walls?

Greets

EDIT

The Promised Picture - It should detect the wall and add it to closestIntersectionObstacle but it doesnt
[image: Promised picture]

Comment: So if I'm reading this right, `LocalPos` is the wall's position relative to the player. But then you say the Y value is 120. If the wall is 120 units away from the player and the bound is only 25, why are you expecting it to detect a possible collision?

Comment: @Tesserex i will upload a photo for more detail in half an hour it'll describe what i think. In words: localpos.Y is the position in the world.. not relative to the player..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment my reading was wrong. I thought LocalPos was relative to the player, because I assumed that's what `HelperMethods.PointToLocalSpace` was supposed to be doing. But if `LocalPos` is still world coords, then your description at the end of the question gives it away.

Your if statement:

```
if (Math.Abs(LocalPos.Y) < ExpandedRadius)
```

can be translated into English like so:

```
if the wall's vertical position on the screen is less than the bounding distance...
```

Comparing an absolute position to a relative distance shouldn't make much sense intuitively.

It should be asking if the *distance* between the player and the wall is less than `ExpandingRadius`.

```
double playerDistance = /* Calculate distance between player and wall */
if (playerDistance < ExpandedRadius)
```

Comment: I've got it sort of working, yet now it doesn't work with the detectionbox but instead the playersDistance so i should just change that, and i'm done thanks man!